Virtual directory mapping not working in Weblogic
I´m currently using Java 8 and JEE 8 as well, my version of weblogic is 14.1.1 (All working on Windows). I want to make a virutal directory mapping for a URL that is comming from the Front-End but when I get to the url pattern /insurance/ my virtual directory doesnt recognize it. My root directory is /xpertys-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT and when it try the url just in the browser doesnt work either, What am I doing wrong?
Here is the complete URL http://localhost:7001/insurance/BS/digitalizacion/expedientesEspeciales/784183/44/credenPolizaIndiviudal2254240628160858080009290.8885072304607314.pdf
And here is the absolute path
C:\Users\Desarrollo\Desktop\BackEnd\Insurance\Digitalizacion\insurance\BS\digitalizacion\expedientesEspeciales\784183\44\
PD: I made sure that the directory on my PC exists and all the files in it, the direction is also correct.
PD2: I clarify that I also put the context root at the url http://localhost:7001//xpertys-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT/insurance/BS/... but that doesnt work either.
This is my weblogic.xml file
weblogic.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.9/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <context-root>/xpertys-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</context-root>
    <container-descriptor>
        <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
        <prefer-forward-query-string>true</prefer-forward-query-string>
    </container-descriptor>
    <virtual-directory-mapping>
        <local-path>C:/Users/Desarrollo/Desktop/BackEnd/Insurance/Digitalizacion</local-path>
        <url-pattern>/insurance/*</url-pattern>
    </virtual-directory-mapping>
</weblogic-web-app>

The files in my directory that I want to access.
Files in the url
Error given in Chrome

Add the full url and the files paths as text.

What do you mean "as text" and where do I have to add it?

You can [edit] your question to add/modify it.

Done, sorry for the late, is that what you mean?

Please add the absolute path of the file.

Done, sorry im new at this :(

You still there buddy?
